# ufw reset vs. disable / enable

Tags: ufw

When is it appropriate to `ufw reload` versus `ufw disable && ufw enable`, and vice versa?

The reason for asking:

According to the `ufw` man page, "**reload** reloads firewall."

However, documentation provided by the community (e.g., [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall), [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-an-ubuntu-and-debian-cloud-server), and [here](https://serverfault.com/a/811746/140347)), instructs us to activate new settings by running:

```
$ sudo ufw disable
$ sudo ufw enable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `sudo ufw reload` simply `reloads` the rules, while `sudo ufw enable` actually calls the `reload` command and also enables it at reboot.

Now note that `sudo ufw disable` was run first so the need for `sudo ufw enable`, and that being said I believe using the above outlined steps for new changes to `ufw` rules is for emphasis as `sudo ufw reload` will still suffice. Test it and see if the new rules don't apply successfully.